# Selenium not following click that opens a new tab

Tags: python, selenium

For the longest time I had an issue with selenium finding a button I was looking for on the page. After a week I got the "brilliant" idea to check the url that selenium was searching the button for. Dummy me, it was the wrong URL.

So the issue is, selenium searches page1 for a specific item. It then clicks it, and by the websites design, it opens page2 in a new tab. How can I get selenium to follow the click and work on the new tab?

I though of using beautiful soup to just copy the url from page1, but the website doesn't show the urls. Instead it shows functions that get the urls. It's really weird and confusing.
Ideas?

```
all_matches = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[text()[contains(., 'Pink')]]")
item = all_matches[0]
actions.move_to_element(item).perform()
item.click()


try:
    print (driver.current_url)
    get_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="getItem"]')
except:
    print 'Cant find button'
else:
    actions.move_to_element(get_button).perform()
    get_button.click()
```

Comment: did you try to use forloop instead od actions.move_to ? ( for item in all matches : item.click() break )

Comment: Check this answer out: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/26800/how-to-switch-from-one-tab-to-another-tab-in-chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selenium treats tabs like windows, so generally, switching to new window/tab is as easy as:

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
```

You may find it helpful to keep track of the windows with vars:

```
main_window = driver.current_window_handle
page2_window = driver.window_handles[-1]
driver.switch_to.window(page2_window)
```

Note that when you want to close the new window/tab, you have to both close & switch back:

```
driver.close()
driver.switch_to.window(main_window)
```